# About an error accessing a field inside Tuple2

Tags: scala, tuples, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i am trying to access to a field within a Tuple2 and compiler is returning me an error. The software tries to push a case class within a kafka topic, then i want to recover it using spark streaming so i can feed a machine learning algorithm and save results within a mongo instance.

Solved!

I finally solved my problem, i am going to post the final solution:

This is the github project:

```
https://github.com/alonsoir/awesome-recommendation-engine/tree/develop
```

build.sbt

```
name := "my-recommendation-spark-engine"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"

val akkaVersion = "2.3.11" // override Akka to be this version to match the one in Spark

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.8.1"
  exclude("javax.jms", "jms")
  exclude("com.sun.jdmk", "jmxtools")
  exclude("com.sun.jmx", "jmxri"),
 //not working play module!! check
 //jdbc,
 //anorm,
 //cache,
 // HTTP client
 "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.1",
 // HTML parser
 "org.jodd" % "jodd-lagarto" % "3.5.2",
 "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1",
 "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.10" % "2.4.0-M2",
 "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test",
 "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.2",
 "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.2",
 "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-core-asl" % "1.6.1",
 "org.scala-tools.testing" % "specs_2.8.0" % "1.6.5" % "test",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.1" ,
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.1" ,
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.1",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.6.1",
 "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.6.2",
 "commons-cli" % "commons-cli" % "1.3.1",
 "com.stratio.datasource" % "spark-mongodb_2.10" % "0.11.1",
 // Akka
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,
 // MongoDB
 "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.10.0"
 )

 packAutoSettings

 //play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

Kafka Producer

```
package example.producer

import play.api.libs.json._
import example.utils._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import example.model.{AmazonProductAndRating,AmazonProduct,AmazonRating}
import example.utils.AmazonPageParser
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future


/**
args(0) : productId
args(1) : userdId

Usage: ./amazon-producer-example 0981531679 someUserId 3.0
*/
object AmazonProducerExample {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val productId = args(0).toString
val userId = args(1).toString
val rating = args(2).toDouble
val topicName = "amazonRatingsTopic"

val producer = Producer[String](topicName)

//0981531679 is Scala Puzzlers...
AmazonPageParser.parse(productId,userId,rating).onSuccess { case amazonRating =>
  //Is this the correct way? the best performance? possibly not, what about using avro or parquet? How can i push data in avro or parquet format?
  //You can see that i am pushing json String to kafka topic, not raw String, but is there any difference? 
  //of course there are differences...
  producer.send(Json.toJson(amazonRating).toString)
  //producer.send(amazonRating.toString)
  println("amazon product with rating sent to kafka cluster..." + amazonRating.toString)
  System.exit(0)
}

}
}
```

This is the definition of necessary case classes (UPDATED), the file is named models.scala:

```
package example.model

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import reactivemongo.bson.Macros

case class AmazonProduct(itemId: String, title: String, url: String, img: String, description: String)
case class AmazonRating(userId: String, productId: String, rating: Double)

case class AmazonProductAndRating(product: AmazonProduct, rating: AmazonRating)

// For MongoDB
object AmazonRating {
implicit val amazonRatingHandler = Macros.handler[AmazonRating]
implicit val amazonRatingFormat = Json.format[AmazonRating]
//added using @Yuval tip
lazy val empty: AmazonRating = AmazonRating("-1", "-1", -1d)
}
```

This is the full code of the spark streaming process:

```
package example.spark

import java.io.File
import java.util.Date

import play.api.libs.json._
import com.google.gson.{Gson,GsonBuilder, JsonParser}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.QueryBuilder
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.{MongoDBList, MongoDBObject}

import reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver
import reactivemongo.api.collections.default.BSONCollection
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument

import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import example.model._

import example.utils.Recommender

/**
* Collect at least the specified number of json amazon products in order to feed recomedation system and feed mongo instance with results.

Usage: ./amazon-kafka-connector 127.0.0.1:9092 amazonRatingsTopic

on mongo shell:

use alonsodb;
db.amazonRatings.find();
*/
object AmazonKafkaConnector {

private var numAmazonProductCollected = 0L
private var partNum = 0
private val numAmazonProductToCollect = 10000000

//this settings must be in reference.conf
private val Database = "alonsodb"
private val ratingCollection = "amazonRatings"
private val MongoHost = "127.0.0.1"
private val MongoPort = 27017
private val MongoProvider = "com.stratio.datasource.mongodb"

private val jsonParser = new JsonParser()
private val gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()

private def prepareMongoEnvironment(): MongoClient = {
  val mongoClient = MongoClient(MongoHost, MongoPort)
  mongoClient
}

private def closeMongoEnviroment(mongoClient : MongoClient) = {
  mongoClient.close()
  println("mongoclient closed!")
}

private def cleanMongoEnvironment(mongoClient: MongoClient) = {
  cleanMongoData(mongoClient)
  mongoClient.close()
}

private def cleanMongoData(client: MongoClient): Unit = {
  val collection = client(Database)(ratingCollection)
  collection.dropCollection()
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
// Process program arguments and set properties

if (args.length < 2) {
  System.err.println("Usage: " + this.getClass.getSimpleName + " <brokers> <topics>")
  System.exit(1)
}

val Array(brokers, topics) = args

println("Initializing Streaming Spark Context and kafka connector...")
// Create context with 2 second batch interval
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AmazonKafkaConnector")
                               .setMaster("local[4]")
                                .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
sc.addJar("target/scala-2.10/blog-spark-recommendation_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
//this checkpointdir should be in a conf file, for now it is hardcoded!
val streamingCheckpointDir = "/Users/aironman/my-recommendation-spark-engine/checkpoint"
ssc.checkpoint(streamingCheckpointDir)

// Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
println("Initialized Streaming Spark Context and kafka connector...")

//create recomendation module
println("Creating rating recommender module...")
val ratingFile= "ratings.csv"
val recommender = new Recommender(sc,ratingFile)
println("Initialized rating recommender module...")
//THIS IS THE MOST INTERESTING PART AND WHAT I NEED!
//THE SOLUTION IS NOT PROBABLY THE MOST EFFICIENT, BECAUSE I HAD TO 
//USE DATAFRAMES, ARRAYs and SEQs BUT IS FUNCTIONAL!
try{
messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {
 val count = rdd.count()
 if (count > 0){
   val json= rdd.map(_._2)
   val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(json) //converts json to DF
   val myRow = dataFrame.select(dataFrame("userId"),dataFrame("productId"),dataFrame("rating")).take(count.toInt)
   println("myRow is: " + myRow)

   val myAmazonRating = AmazonRating(myRow(0).getString(0), myRow(0).getString(1), myRow(0).getDouble(2))
   println("myAmazonRating is: " + myAmazonRating.toString)
   val arrayAmazonRating = Array(myAmazonRating)
   //this method needs Seq[AmazonRating]
   recommender.predictWithALS(arrayAmazonRating.toSeq)
   }//if
})      
}catch{
  case e: IllegalArgumentException => {println("illegal arg. exception")};
  case e: IllegalStateException    => {println("illegal state exception")};
  case e: ClassCastException       => {println("ClassCastException")};
  case e: Exception                => {println(" Generic Exception")};
}finally{

  println("Finished taking data from kafka topic...")
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

println("Finished!")
}
}
```

Thank you all, folks, @Yuval, @Emecas and @Riccardo.cardin.

Recommender.predict signature method looks like:

```
  def predict(ratings: Seq[AmazonRating]) = {
  // train model
  val myRatings = ratings.map(toSparkRating)
  val myRatingRDD = sc.parallelize(myRatings)

  val startAls = DateTime.now
  val model = ALS.train((sparkRatings ++ myRatingRDD).repartition(NumPartitions), 10, 20, 0.01)

  val myProducts = myRatings.map(_.product).toSet
  val candidates = sc.parallelize((0 until productDict.size).filterNot(myProducts.contains))

  // get ratings of all products not in my history ordered by rating (higher first) and only keep the first NumRecommendations
   val myUserId = userDict.getIndex(MyUsername)
   val recommendations = model.predict(candidates.map((myUserId, _))).collect
   val endAls = DateTime.now
   val result = recommendations.sortBy(-_.rating).take(NumRecommendations).map(toAmazonRating)
   val alsTime = Seconds.secondsBetween(startAls, endAls).getSeconds

   println(s"ALS Time: $alsTime seconds")
   result
   }
```

//I think I've been as clear as possible, tell me if you need anything more and thanks for your patience teaching me @Yuval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Diagnosis**

`IllegalStateException` suggests that you are operating over a `StreamingContext` that is already ACTIVE or STOPPED. [see details here (lines 218-231)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adding new inputs, transformations, and output operations after starting a context is not supported
```

**Code Review**

By observing your code `AmazonKafkaConnector` , you are doing `map`, `filter` and  `foreachRDD` into another `foreachRDD` over the same `DirectStream` object called : `messages`

**General Advice:**

*Be functional my friend*, by dividing your logic in small pieces for each one of the tasks you want to perform:

- Streaming
- ML Recommendation
- Persistence
- etc.

That will help you to understand and debug easier the Spark pipeline that you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the statement `rdd.take(count.toInt)` return an `Array[T]`, as stated [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/api/core/spark/RDD.html)

```
def take(num: Int): Array[T]
```

> Take the first num elements of the RDD.

You're saying to your `RDD` to take the first n elements in it. Then, differently from what you guess, you've not a object of type `Tuple2`, but an array.

If you want to print each element of the array, you can use the method `mkString` defined on the `Array` type to obtain a single `String` with all the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're trying to do is is simply a `map` over a `DStream`. A `map` operation is a projection from type `A` to type `B`, where `A` is a `String` (that you're receiving from Kafka), and `B` is your case class `AmazonRating`.

Let's add an `empty` value to your `AmazonRating`:

```
case class AmazonRating(userId: String, productId: String, rating: Double)

object AmazonRating {
  lazy val empty: AmazonRating = AmazonRating("-1", "-1", -1d)
}
```

Now let's parse the JSONs:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils
    .createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder]
    (ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

messages
      .map { case (_, jsonRating) => 
        val format = Json.format[AmazonRating]
        val jsValue = Json.parse(record)
        format.reads(jsValue) match {
          case JsSuccess(rating, _) => rating
          case JsError(_) => AmazonRating.empty
      }
      .filter(_ != AmazonRating.empty)
      .foreachRDD(_.foreachPartition(it => recommender.predict(it.toSeq)))
```

Comment: Ok, but the error is simply that he confused an object of type `Array[T]` with an object of type `Tuple2`, doesn't he?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin No, he has an `Array[(String, String)]` because he didn't deserialize the data coming in from Kafka. He has a tuple because Kafka sends both the key and value, and he hasn't done anything to transform it into his case class.

Comment: He has an `Array` because of this statement `val someMessages = rdd.take(count.toInt)`.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin I understand that this is what the error message is saying, and you're right the he has an `Array[(String, String)]`. But I'm look at his code and I see this comment: *"predict method needs only Seq[AmazonRating]"* and I'm assuming he actually needs to work with the objects, not with a tuple.

Comment: That's ok. You've got the big vision ;)

Comment: Thank you @Yuval for the assistance, but still not working. This is the exception: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$4) => x$4.toSeq)
[error]         .foreachRDD(_.foreachPartition(recommender.predict(_.toSeq))) Should i close this one and open a new one?

Comment: @aironman It's missing the underscore. Did you add it? I've modified the code to explicitly include a parameter name. Try it now.

Comment: @Yuval, yes, i added it, compiling fine, but a runtime error happens:                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast to [B

Comment: Hi @Yuval, after adding a checkpoint dir to spark streaming process, the exception changed and the process does not die. You can see the exception here: http://pastebin.com/h5CguSxf

Comment: Hi @Yuval, i was thinking that it is not a good idea to have an inner foreachRDD.foreachpartition... yes, it compiles but still not working, it crashes at runtime...